# How to avoid Ecto from adding prefix to references on has_many relationship

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have the following schema:

```
schema "products" do
    field :product_id, :integer
    field :title, :string
    has_many :variants, MyApp.Variant, references: :product_id
    timestamps
end

schema "variants" do
    field :variant_id, :integer
    field :title, :string
    belongs_to :product, MyApp.Product
    timestamps()
end
```

I want to link the variant to product by using the product_id field in the product table instead of the default id field.

The problem I am having is when I query a product and preload it variants, I got  error pointing to the following:

```
from v in MyApp.Variant,
  where: v.product_product_id in ^[198977],
  order_by: [asc: v.product_product_id],
  select: {v.product_product_id, v}
```

Ecto thinks that the foreign key in the variants table is product_product_id. Ecto add the prefix *product_*.

How do I stop Ecto from adding the prefix? Prefix is only good for id field.

For some reason, I cannot use the id field in the products table to link to variants table. I must use a different field.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the belongs_to in the schema "variants" to:

```
belongs_to :product, MyApp.Product, foreign_key: :product_id
```

Also to use a different field name for a primary key in a schema you need to use `@primary_key` passing a tuple `{field_name, type, options}` for example:

```
@primary_key {:product_id, :id, autogenerate: true}
```

Let me know if this helps.